# jQuery не работает с несколькими формами на странице

Tags: javascript, jquery

Доброго!
Сразу к делу: в документе есть 2 формы, выполняю запрос jQuery:
    `var ii = $('input', '#frm-login');`
в ii попадают 'input' из обеих форм, а не только '#frm-login' ((.
Cтруктура документа:

```
<body>
  ...
  <div class="..." ...>
    <form id="frm-login" ...>...</form>
    <form id="frm-work" ...>...</form>
  </div>
  ...
</body>
```

Как обойти такое поведение - не проблема, можно написать пару "лишних" строчек кода. 
Вопрос: ПОЧЕМУ так ?

Comment: Нужно прочитать документацию, а не писать лишний код.

Comment: Костыль №1 найден, "подопытную" форму можно обернуть в <div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> в ii попадают 'input' из обеих форм

Как Вы это выяснили?

> ПОЧЕМУ так ?

Это не так.

Вот какой код был у автора вопроса:

```js
var ii = $('input', '#frm-login');
console.log(ii.length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <form id="frm-login"><input /><button type="submit"/> </form>
  <form id="frm-work"><input /><input /><input /></form>
</div>
```

*Update*

Вас понял.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button

> Tag omission  - None, both the starting and ending tag are mandatory.
>
> Пропуск тэгов - Отсутствует. Как открывающий так и закрывающий тэги
>   обязательны.

Обратите внимание на то, что три инпута второй формы находятся внутри кнопки. Таким образом, вторая форма со своими инпутами находится внутри первой.

Исправление: заменить

```
<button type="submit"/>
```

на

```
<button type="submit"></button>
```

Comment: Как Вы это выяснили? - дебагером crome, использовал "jquery-1.10.2.js", может в более новых версиях исправили данное поведение ...

Comment: @ЮрийКарпенко  Пожалуйста, не надо вносить значительные измененения в  ответ. Договоритесь с авторм ответа через комментарии.

Comment: @Igor вы абсолютно правы, я на ходу менял тег с <input type="submit"/> на <button type="submit"/> и не позаботился правильно закрыть его. Огромное спасибо!